# Upgrade of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS fails with 403 Forbidden errors

Tags: 18.04, ppa, lts

```
    Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

    enter code here
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or add/remove/edit any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: @user9566093 How do you connect to the Internet? WiFi or Ethernet? Are you the person paying for the Internet service, or does someone else? This is the kind of error I would expect if the router controlling Internet access was blocking me.

Comment: Did you add nrbrtx repository to fix ubuntu 18.04 problem with ctrl+shift key combination?

Comment: Got the same error and just retried. Appears to have been caused by a network error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URLs work, try to visit one of them with your browser (from the same network), for example:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease

I you also get error 403 in the browser, then the most likely reason is a (transparent) proxy denying access to that resource.

Comment: Actually i am using my own internet connection and the urls work perfectly when i visit them. I have no idea regarding my source.list , can you provide the solution for that.

Comment: Maybe if you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You could add the result of `tail -n +1 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to the question.

Comment: I am using a client's machine remotely and suspect that they may have a firewall up blocking access, but I can the URLs open perfectly fine in the browser.